# How different would the results be if moderator elections simply asked who wants to be a mod and picked top reputation?

Tags: discussion

> Tone is really hard to convey when posting text online so please know that I'm not trying to whine or complain or anything.

How many members of this community (or any stack exchange for that matter) vote for a person based on any measurement other than reputation earned?

### I can't think of a more accurate way to vote for a good moderator than simply clicking next to the person SE says contributes a lot.

Isn't reputation and badges the beauty of SE and a good reason why it works so well?  Anything a member does that contributes to the greater good is automatically recognized.  Does anyone honestly expect a community of this size to look deeper than raw stats when electing a moderator?

Currently there is one outlier among the top vote getters and I must say that I am really tempted to vote for 5,500 based on outlier status alone.

`votes / reputation`

`189 / 36,500`

`139 / 49,000`

`127 /  5,500`

`105 / 20,000`

`67  /  9,000`

**I'm curious to hear your thoughts.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that actually happened at SharePoint.SE, where highest rep running got mod place number one. The second place went to my friend Robert, who was a 5k user a year ago, at the time of the election. Third place was mine to keep, by a fraction. And I was a 3,5k user then.

There were at least three 10k+ users who weren't elected. One of them was obvious, he constantly ends up in comment battle on which technique is the best. But the other two? It's just a guess, but they weren't active on meta, where you're supposed to have discussions.

So the advice is that activity pays off, being active on meta is essential, collect all badges, where Sportsmanship is the key. It says something about your attitude towards colleagues at UX.

A last thought, I'm probably older than average (pushing 47 this year), have 7 years management experience, and last but not least – I'm Swedish. ;-)

Comment: i had to accept this answer based on prior experience but mostly because you are Swedish

Comment: Biased much Dave? LoL!! JK. Yea ... I've never really gotten into the meta side of things just because in my experience it's a pretty negative area no matter where I've been.  Lots of egos and down-votes, so I strayed away and kept active on the main sites unless I found a bug or wanted a feature request or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 positions open and the top reputation users will get them; that's just how it works. There are times where it doesn't, but it seems it's usually the case regardless.

To me :

- People don't *really* want to participate (it actually takes time).

  - Case in point, look at how many questions were actually submitted to the candidates that didn't come from the candidates themselves.

    - Then, they don't even really read the answers to the questions for all the candidates.

      - I was first to answer the questions and didn't even get 1 vote and it was there for awhile before anyone else answered.
  - You get a badge for voting, so people just come in, see who has the highest reputation or the highest current score and vote them up.

    - This is very evident in the final phase when you see the results.
- Then you have people that try to discredit other candidates, like your "outlier" did to me by accusing me of plagiarism on my nomination thread. After awhile we eventually cleaned it up, but it was already too late, the smear campaign worked.

  - I looked at other the candidates' answers and found places where I could've started a debate on their nomination threads, as your "outlier" did to me, but why? It's *not mod-like at all* to do that, especially in an election, in my opinion. Your "outlier" should've talked with me in private about their accusation (which obviously did not happen) *and which is why I don't think I could vote for them this go 'round.*

Plain and simple:

***[@BennySkogberg](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/4679/benny-skogberg) deserves to be a mod and will be.*** He's super nice, has a high rep, is active, and does all the things mods already do with the 10k and 20k tools he has.

As far as the rest, I think there are some people that are better suited to be mods that should've nominated themselves like :

- **[@DA01](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/1740/da01)**
- **[@MervinJohnsingh](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/5113/mervin-johnsingh)**
- **[@BartGijssens](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/5657/bart-gijssens)**

One of them would've made a great 2nd place mod behind Benny.

That's just my 2 cents.

Comment: thanks for your thoughts code maverick - you are a stellar part of this community.

Comment: I appreciate it Dave.

Comment: CodeMaverick, I can understand that you're a bit angry at my allegations of plagiarism, but to be fair when I pointed them out, I wasn't planning on running as a mod, just trying to make sure that whoever was elected would respect intellectual property.  A private message was not an option because there are no private messages on SE (except for mods).

Comment: When you claimed that both of your instances of plagiarism were accidental, I decided to give you the benefit of the doubt and suggested we clear up the comments to keep your nomination thread clean.  It wasn't until several days after those comments were cleared and several people had suggested I nominate myself that I decided to run as a mod.  If I had known I would be running, I would never have posted against another candidate, so I apologize if you think I hurt your campaign.

Comment: @3nafish - First of all, I kept my post anonymous and didn't call you out by name on purpose, but since you commented, I have no ill will toward you. It's politics and as I pointed out, most likely, the top 2 reputation leaders will get the position. That said, what I can say to your _"no private messages on SE"_ is that you could've invited me to a discussion in a chat room. That's one way it would've not been on my thread.

Comment: @3nafish - Secondly, I could argue that people that saw your allegations of 2 cherry-picked answers out of, as of right now, 111 here on UX.SE and 434 on Stack Overflow, propelled people push you to nominate yourself. Then the trickle-down theory applied after that. But again, I have no ill will towards you. Best of luck in the election phase.

Comment: @CodeMaverick thanks for your support! It warms my heart to hear those words from you! Don't give up at this stage! Please continue on your journey towards greater answers, more badges, higher reps and I'm confident you'll get what you want. Maybe not this year, but there will be more elections. Your contributions are noticeable, and we need you here with us!